# C++ project folder External Dependencies contains only .h and .hpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm working on a C++ project in Visual Studio, the bulk of which was designed by someone else, and I have limited knowledge of computer programming outside of writting simple classes and using them. In the solution explorer, there's a folder called "External Dependencies", and it contains a ton of .h and .hpp files, but no .cpp files.

In the code editor, if I go to some block of code containing a function call to a function declared in a file in the External Dependencies folder, and I right-click>go-to definition on that function, it will take me to the declaration, not the definition. It's as if the project doesn't know where the .cpp files are, but it must, otherwise these functions wouldn't work.

What kind of folder is External Dependencies?

What is the process of setting one of these up in Visual Studio so that the compiler knows the definition of the functions your using in your program?

Comment: As the name implies, those are the header files for externally defined objects. The majority is likely the Windows API, with implementations shipped in library code (usually DLL files). You cannot set up Visual Studio to find source code that's not on your machine. If you need to see the implementation, you're going to have to study assembly language.

Comment: Ok. Where are the DLL's? How do you tell VS where they are?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't care about those DLLs. They are located somewhere on the [dynamic-link library search order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx). Visual Studio does care about the import libraries (LIB) files, though. Neither one will get you source code, though, which is apparently what you are after.

Comment: I'm not after the source code. Read the question please.

Comment: *"It's as if the project doesn't know where the .cpp files are, but it must, otherwise these functions wouldn't work."* - I took that to mean: *"Where are the implementations?"* and I explained, that they are compiled into object code, linked with information entirely stored in import libraries. No implementation files required (the Windows SDK doesn't ship with Windows' source code). If you meant to ask a different question, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to include the appropriate header files with the methods you're using in your program? I think you still need to have all of the appropriate #include directives. So, if you include the header files

```
#include <library>
```

or

```
#include "header_file.h"
```

that would enable the compiler to have access to the methods of the class you're trying to use.

If the header files don't include the actual implementation (it's a common practice I think to split classes into .h header files and .cpp implementation files), you also need to put the include directives in the .cpp implementation files.